# C++ code in C#, Wrappers and #includes

Tags: c#, c++

When using C++ code in C#, if the class you are trying to wrap has #include's that aren't standard c++ libraries, Do all of the #includes also have to be in their own wrapper or does the class functions directly being used for the c# code only have to be put into a wrapper?

Comment: What kind of wrapper?

Comment: Visual Studio class library wrapper

Comment: You're going to have to post an example to make sure we know what you're referring to - right now it's not clear at all what kind of "wrapper" you're talking about.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqsj__ZVm-c The same exact way of wrapping as in this video.